# ClosedXml set style to a spitted range with multiple columns c#

Tags: c#, excel, report, closedxml

Both of these commands are working fine

```
worksheet.Range("B9:B41").Style.Alignment.SetHorizontal(XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center);
                    worksheet.Range("J9:L41").Style.Alignment.SetHorizontal(XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center);
```

But if i merge them to one command like these:

```
worksheet.Range("B9:B41,J9:L41").Style.Alignment.SetHorizontal(XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center);
```

Im getting an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

is there a way to overcome these?

Comment: Read ClosedXML documentation/Wiki: https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Multiple-Ranges

Comment: how does it differ from what I did?

Comment: Ah, i see your confusion. Pay attention to the difference between "ws.Range" and "ws.Range**s**". (`Range` != `Ranges`)

Comment: thanks, such a stupid mistake